# MySQL prepared statement returns false

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I have the following **working** MySQL insert:

```
$tableSelect = $_POST["tableSelect"];
$companyName = $_POST["companyName"];
$telephone = $_POST["telephone"];
$fax = $_POST["fax"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$address = $_POST["address"];
$postcode = $_POST["postcode"];
$category = $_POST["category"];
$contact = $_POST["contact"];
$contactTel = $_POST["contactTel"];
$contactEmail = $_POST["contactEmail"];
$sql = "INSERT INTO $tableSelect (companyName,telephone,fax,email,address,postcode,category,contact,contactTel,
    contactEmail) VALUES ('$companyName','$telephone','$fax','$email','$address','$postcode','$category',
    '$contact','$contactTel','$contactEmail');";
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
```

However, I've tried to change this into a prepared statement to protect myself from injection, like so:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO suppliers (companyName,telephone,fax,email,address,postcode,
    category,contact,contactTel,contactEmail) VALUES(:companyName, :telephone, :fax, :email, :address,
    :postcode, :category, :contact, :contactTel, :contactEmail);");
if ($stmt !== FALSE) {
    $stmt->bindParam(':companyName',$companyName);
    $stmt->bindParam(':telephone',$telephone);
    $stmt->bindParam(':fax',$fax);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email',$email);
    $stmt->bindParam(':address',$address);
    $stmt->bindParam(':postcode',$postcode);
    $stmt->bindParam(':category',$category);
    $stmt->bindParam(':contact',$contact);
    $stmt->bindParam(':contactTel',$contactTel);
    $stmt->bindParam(':contactEmail',$contactEmail);
    $companyName = $_POST["companyName"];
    $telephone = $_POST["telephone"];
    $fax = $_POST["fax"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $address = $_POST["address"];
    $postcode = $_POST["postcode"];
    $category = $_POST["category"];
    $contact = $_POST["contact"];
    $contactTel = $_POST["contactTel"];
    $contactEmail = $_POST["contactEmail"];
    $stmt->execute();
}
else {
    echo "Could not connect";
}
```

Every time I run it, `$stmt` returns false. It's the first time I've used prepared statements and I'm fairly new to MySQL so some pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It might be an issue that you're binding a variable called `tableSelect` that isn't used in your query. But in your original query, you're using that for the table name, and you cannot use a bound parameter for the table name.

Comment: yet another typo-based offtopic question...

Comment: Hi, sorry, I forgot to remove tableSelect before I posted the question - I have tried removing it and it hasn't worked

Comment: Why is it offtopic? Or typo based for that matter?

Comment: **because** you forgot to remove tableSelect before posted the question

Comment: But removing it doens't fix it - I've already tried removing it and I've changed that now.

Comment: the question is not "does it work or not" but "is your question offtopic or not". Every question that asks "why my code doesn't work" is an offtopic.

Comment: Says who? I'm asking for help with my code. I've told you what's going wrong. I'd like a more experience MySQL/PHP programmer to help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for mysqli is wrong. You have tried using PDO. For mysqli

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO suppliers (companyName,telephone,fax,email,address,postcode,category,contact,contactTel,contactEmail) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");



if($stmt){

        $stmt->bind_param('ssssssssss',$companyName,$telephone,$fax,$email,$address,$postcode,$category,$contact,$contactTel,$contactEmail);
        //s for string, i for integer, d for double, b for blob
        $stmt->execute();
}else{

       echo($con->error); //TO display Error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though your question is a sure offtopic, here are some pointers

Assuming you are using PDO for the second example (for some reason you didn't indicate it in your question)

1. you have to tell PDO to throw exceptions

   ```
   $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
   ```

   it will let you to at least have an error message to think of.
2. **a table name should never be supplied by client side**.
3. adjust your bound variables to make them fit the query
4. Instead of that long and windy code just remove unnecessary members from $_POST array and **pass it to execute**

something like this

```
$con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$sql = "INSERT INTO suppliers 
 (companyName,telephone,fax,email,address,postcode,
  category,contact,contactTel,contactEmail) 
 VALUES 
 (:companyName, :telephone, :fax, :email, :address,
  :postcode, :category, :contact, :contactTel, :contactEmail)";
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
unset ($_POST['submit']);
// make sure you unset all the useless members
$stmt->execute($_POST);
```

Comment: should unset() not be followed by a ;?

Comment: Shouldn't you tell us at last, **what driver you are using**? And it it's mysqli - where did you get that syntax than?

Comment: Yet another typo-based answer...
I've accepted an answer and clearly from that answer having worked it's mysqli. As I said, I'm new to MySQL so I wasn't sure on the difference.